# make summary data frame from a string input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to summarize a log string.

```
trn_log = "Item1   10  Item2   1  Item1  -5  Item3   40  Item2   -1"
```

And if we summarize to a data frame of 2 rows and 2 columns we get a list like this
Item1 5
Item3 40

the result data frame's rows should be automatically adjusted

so for

```
trn_log = "Item1   10  Item2   5  Item1  -5  Item3   40  Item2   -1"
```

the resulting data frame is

Item1 5
Item2 4
Item3 40

I am using python 3

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I am trying to summarize a log string."  Do you want to convert the string to a dataframe with two columns, or something else?

Comment: yes if can convert its all fine

Comment: I have tried data = pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(ransaction_log)) But i am getting \n and getting only one column, the items should be in one column and the numbers in another column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def build_frame(tl):
    itms = []
    vals = []
    for ntry in tl.split(" "):
        if ntry:
            if ntry[:3].lower() == 'ite':
                itms.append(ntry)
            else:
                vals.append(int(ntry))
    return pd.DataFrame({'Items': itms, 'Values':vals})
```

then executing `build_frame(trn_log)` yields:

```
    Items   Values
0   Item1   10
1   Item2   1
2   Item1   -5
3   Item3   40
4   Item2   -1
```

​

Comment: Machine- Win 10, Anaconda, Python 3.7
ValueError  Traceback 
<ipython-input-43-4ccfc7d8cf6d> in <module>
     11                 vals.append(int(ntry))
     12     return pd.DataFrame({'Items': itms, 'Values':vals})
---> 13 build_frame(ransaction_log)
<ipython-input-43-4ccfc7d8cf6d> in build_frame(tl)
      9                 itms.append(ntry)
     10             else:
---> 11                 vals.append(int(ntry))
     12     return pd.DataFrame({'Items': itms, 'Values':vals})
     13 build_frame(ransaction_log)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\nItem1'

Comment: Your error tells me that your input trn_log doesn't look like your example, there seem to be '\n' chars in the string.  Please verify that the trn_log used to run the script looks like your example or update the example to show realistic trn_log data